# Mostrar contenido de consulta Mysql en tablas en FPDF

Tags: mysql, pdf

Estoy generando una salida en formato PDF con la utilidad FPDF usando sus clases esta definido el cuerpo de la siguiente manera:

```js
require('/fpdf.php');

include 'clases.php';

class PDF extends FPDF {
    

protected $col = 0; // Columna actual
protected $y0;      // Ordenada de comienzo de la columna

   
function Header() {
$this->Image('imagenes/logos/FondoResguardo2.jpg',0,0,300,0);
    
} 

function Footer() {
    parent::Footer();
    $this->SetY(-15);
    $this->SetFont('Arial','I',6);
    $this->Cell(0, 10,utf8_decode('PÁGINA').$this->PageNo().' DE {nb}',0,0,'L');
}

function DependenciaTable()
{  
    $this->SetFont('','B');
    $this->SetXY(10,45);
    $fill = True;
    $this->SetFillColor(224,235,255);
    $this->SetTextColor(0);
    $this->SetDrawColor(224,235,255);
    $this->Cell(137,5,'DATOS DE LA DEPENDENCIA', 1,1,'C',$fill);
   
    $this->MultiCell(137,20,'',1);
    $this->SetXY(10,50);
    $this->Cell(137,5,'DEPENDENCIA:', 0,1,'L');
    $this->SetXY(35,50);
    $this->Cell(80,5,utf8_decode($nombre),0,1,'L',0);
    $this->SetXY(10,55);
    $this->Cell(137,5,'UR:', 0,1,'L');
    $this->SetXY(35,55);
    $this->Cell(80,5,utf8_decode($unidad) ,0,1,'L',0);
    $this->SetXY(10,60);
    $this->Cell(137,5,utf8_decode('DIRECCIÓN GENERAL:'), 0,1,'L');
    $this->SetXY(35,60);
    $this->Cell(80,5,utf8_decode('DIRECCIÓN DE FINANZAS' ),0,1,'L',0);
    $this->SetXY(10,65);
    $this->Cell(137,5,utf8_decode('DIRECCIÓN DE AREA:'), 0,1,'L');
    $this->SetXY(35,65);
    $this->Cell(80,5,utf8_decode($nombreUnidad),0,1,'L',0);
    $this->Ln();
}
function UsuarioTable()
{   

    $this->SetFont('','B');
    $this->SetXY(153,45);
    $fill = True;
    $this->SetFillColor(224,235,255);
    $this->SetTextColor(0);
    $this->SetDrawColor(224,235,255);
    $this->Cell(137,5,'DATOS DEL USUARIO', 1,1,'C',$fill);
    
    $this->SetXY(153,50);
    $this->MultiCell(137,20,'',1);
    $this->SetXY(153,50);
    $this->Cell(137,5,'NUMERO DE EMPLEADO:', 0,1,'L');
    $this->SetXY(185,50);
    $this->Cell(80,5,utf8_decode($numero_Empleado),0,1,'L',0);
    $this->SetXY(153,55);
    $this->Cell(137,5,'NOMBRE DE EMPLEADO:', 0,1,'L');
    $this->SetXY(185,55);
    $this->Cell(80,5,utf8_decode($nombre_Empleado),0,1,'L',0);
    $this->SetXY(153,60);
    $this->Cell(137,5,'NIVEL TABULAR:', 0,1,'L');
    $this->SetXY(185,60);
    $this->Cell(80,5,utf8_decode($nivel),0,1,'L',0);
    $this->SetXY(153,65);
    $this->Cell(137,5,'CATEGORIA O PUESTO:', 0,1,'L');
    $this->SetXY(185,65);
    $this->Cell(80,5,utf8_decode($puesto),0,1,'L',0);
    $this->Ln();
}

function ActivosTable($header)
{
    // Colores, ancho de línea y fuente en negrita
    $this->SetXY(10,75);
    $this->SetFillColor(0, 0, 139);
    $this->SetTextColor(255);
    $this->SetDrawColor(224,235,255);
    $this->SetLineWidth(.3);
    $this->SetFont('','B');
    // Cabecera
    $w = array(6,25,19,15,60,40,25,20,20,25,25);
    for($i=0;$i<count($header);$i++)
        $this->Cell(utf8_decode($w[$i]),6,$header[$i],1,0,'C',true);
    $this->Ln();
    // Restauración de colores y fuentes
    $this->SetFillColor(224,235,255);
    $this->SetTextColor(0);
    $this->SetFont('');
    // Datos
    $fill = false;
     $this->Cell(utf8_decode($w[0]),5,utf8_decode($a+1),'LR',0,'L',$fill);
     $this->Cell(utf8_decode($w[1]),5,utf8_decode($unidad),'LR',0,'L',$fill);
     $this->Cell(utf8_decode($w[2]),5,utf8_decode($activo),'LR',0,'L',$fill);
     $this->Cell(utf8_decode($w[3]),5,utf8_decode($subActivo),'LR',0,'C',$fill);
     $this->Cell(utf8_decode($w[4]),5,utf8_decode($descripcion),'LR',0,'L',$fill);
     $this->Cell(utf8_decode($w[5]),5,utf8_decode($material),'LR',0,'L',$fill);
     $this->Cell(utf8_decode($w[6]),5,utf8_decode($color),'LR',0,'L',$fill);
     $this->Cell(utf8_decode($w[7]),5,utf8_decode($marca),'LR',0,'L',$fill);
     $this->Cell(utf8_decode($w[8]),5,utf8_decode($modelo),'LR',0,'L',$fill);
     $this->Cell(utf8_decode($w[9]),5,utf8_decode($numeroSerie),'LR',0,'L',$fill);
     $this->Cell(utf8_decode($w[10]),5,utf8_decode($estado_Bien),'LR',0,'L',$fill);
     $this->Ln();
     $fill = !$fill;
    } 
    
    // Línea de cierre
    $this->Cell(array_sum($w),1,'','T',1);
    $this->Cell(280,3,'',0,1,'');
    $this->SetFont('','B',6);
    $this->Multicell(0,5,utf8_decode('NOTA: Los bienes que aparecen en el presente resguardo son propiedad de  '),0,0,'L','L');
    $this->Multicell(0,5,utf8_decode('parcial o total de los mismos, estara obligado al pago de los deducibles respectivos.'),0,0,'L','L');
    $this->Multicell(0,5,utf8_decode('fundamento en los Artículos '),0,0,'L','L');
    $this->Multicell(0,5,utf8_decode('Articulos  El presente resguardo sustituye a los de las fechas anteriores.'),0,0,'L','L');
    $this->Cell(280,3,'',0,1,'');
    $this->Cell(30,10,'OBSERVACIONES:',1,1,'');
    $this->SetXY(40,143);
    $this->MultiCell(250,10,' ',1,1,'');
    $this->Cell(30,5,utf8_decode('TOTAL DE ACTIVOS:'),1,1,'');
    $this->SetXY(40,153);
    $this->Cell(30,5,utf8_decode($a),1,1,'');
    $this->Cell(30,5,utf8_decode('ELABORACIÓN:'),1,1,'');
    $this->SetXY(40,158);
    $this->Cell(30,5,utf8_decode('Fecha de Impresión:'),1,1,'');
     
  }
  
function firmas(){
    $this->SetXY(80,183);
    $this->Cell(50,5,utf8_decode('NOMBRE Y FIRMA DEL USUARIO'),1,1,'C');
    $this->SetXY(180,183);
    $this->Cell(50,5,utf8_decode('NOMBRE Y FIRMA DEL TITULAR DE LA U.R.'),1,1,'C');
  }


   
}
```

Cuando la lista de artículos no excede de 13 se muestra perfectamente el PDF, pero si hay mas de 15 elementos mostrados en la tabla se sobrepone el contenido de la tabla  en la segunda hoja y en la tercera  y así sucesivamente sobre el logo y las otras cabeceras denominadas DependenciaTable() y UsuarioTable() hay manera de hacer que solo muestre 10 a 15 registros por pagina entre la cabecera y el pie de pagina por cada pagina que se genere cuando sean mas de 15 registros?

Agradezco el favor de su atención

Answer (score 1):

Resuelto:
Utilizando la siguiente linea de código se resolvió este inconveniente por si a alguien le sirve...

```
$pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(1,$valor);
```

Esta variable $valor puede ser alimentada o escrito directamente un valor decimal: 10, 20 ,30 o 40 en base a la cantidad de celdas que quieras se desplace.

Saludos